# JBoss Hibernate conflict with SessionFactory and JNDI

Tags: hibernate, jboss, jndi, sessionfactory

I am starting a project using ICEFaces and Hibernate on a JBoss AplicationServer and now I am stuck getting Hibernate to work.

The problem is that my DAO classes cant get the SassionFacade.
I think Hibernate is not creating one because of same conflicts with the JNDI

What I did so far:

setting up my database with MySQL. I used this tutorial: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7
(I installed the JDBC driver as a model) not so sure if it worked because when the server starts it looks like he is loading a other driver

```
18:30:26,980 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
```

Than I pretty much used the first side of this tutorial:
http://www.packtpub.com/article/developing-applications-with-jboss-and-hibernate-1
and it looks liked it worked, i see my database and the tables but the flag Session Factory is empty and show me this warning:

```
2012-01-26 18:36:25,177 WARN Worker-14 org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Could not bind factory to JNDIjavax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getNameParser(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper.bind(NamingHelper.java:75)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory.addInstance(SessionFactoryObjectFactory.java:113)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:378)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1385)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration$4.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:268)
at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(ConsoleConfiguration.java:263)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazySessionFactoryAdapter.getChildren(LazySessionFactoryAdapter.java:43)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:100)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:106)
at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:235)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

I remember that at same point I had same Session Factorys there bot don't remember what I changed that they diassapeard.

Because it is just a warning I was going on with the tutorial and successfully generated the classes to my table and the DAOs than I was writing a little test program and used one of the DAOs and get the following error:

```
18:42:44,232 SCHWERWIEGEND [db.fassaden.hibernate.PlattenHome] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3) Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: SessionFactory -- service jboss.naming.context.java.SessionFactory
at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:92)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:177)
at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:87)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:213)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_17]
at db.fassaden.hibernate.PlattenHome.getSessionFactory(PlattenHome.java:26) [classes:]
at db.fassaden.hibernate.PlattenHome.<init>(PlattenHome.java:22) [classes:]
at fassadenkalkulation.kalkulation.testhibernate(kalkulation.java:21) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_17]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_17]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_17]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_17]
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Beta1.jar:2.0.0.Beta1]
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Beta1.jar:2.0.0.Beta1]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Beta1.jar:2.0.0.Beta1]
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Beta1.jar:2.0.0.Beta1]
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Beta1.jar:2.0.0.Beta1]
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Beta1.jar:2.0.0.Beta1]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Beta1.jar:2.0.0.Beta1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:151) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.CR1b.jar:7.1.0.CR1b]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:897) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:626) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:2033) [jbossweb-7.0.7.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_17]
18:42:44,237 SCHWERWIEGEND [javax.faces.event] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3) Beim Aufrufen des Aktionszielgeräts 'java.lang.IllegalStateException' für Komponente '#{kalkulation.testhibernate}' wurde '_t8' erhalten.  ...
```

This is the Servers standalone.xml

```
<datasources> <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS">
                <connection-url>
                    jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fassaden
                </connection-url>
                <driver>
                    com.mysql
                </driver>
                <transaction-isolation>
                    TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
                </transaction-isolation>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>
                        10
                    </min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>
                        100
                    </max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>
                        true
                    </prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>
                        root
                    </user-name>
                    <password>
                        1taste
                    </password>
                </security>
                <statement>
                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>
                        32
                    </prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    <share-prepared-statements>
                        true
                    </share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>
                    jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
                </connection-url>
                <driver>
                    h2
                </driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>
                        sa
                    </user-name>
                    <password>
                        sa
                    </password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <xa-datasource-class>
                        com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource
                    </xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>
                        org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
                    </xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

My hibernate configuration (hibernate.cfg.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="SessionFactory">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">1taste</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fassaden</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The from Hibernate generated DAO (PlattenHome.java)

```
package db.fassaden.hibernate;
// Generated 26.01.2012 15:18:18 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1


import java.util.List;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.hibernate.LockMode;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Example;

/**
 * Home object for domain model class Platten.
 * @see db.fassaden.hibernate.Platten
 * @author Hibernate Tools
 */
public class PlattenHome {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(PlattenHome.class);

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();

    protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        try {
            return (SessionFactory) new InitialContext().lookup("SessionFactory");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI", e);
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI");
        }
    }
    ...

    public Platten findById( java.lang.Integer id) {
        log.debug("getting Platten instance with id: " + id);
        try {
            Platten instance = (Platten) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .get("db.fassaden.hibernate.Platten", id);
            if (instance==null) {
                log.debug("get successful, no instance found");
            }
            else {
                log.debug("get successful, instance found");
            }
            return instance;
        }
        catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("get failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
```

and how I use it:

```
public void testhibernate(ActionEvent e){
    PlattenHome pdao = new PlattenHome();
    Platten platte = new Platten();
    platte = pdao.findById(1);
    this.setName(platte.getMaterial());
    System.out.println("test");
    System.out.println(platte.getMaterial());
}
```

I just noticed that if I rebuild the hibernate configuration now after the server has started it gives me a other Warning

```
2012-01-26 18:48:55,359 WARN main org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Could not unbind factory from JNDI
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.unbind(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory.removeInstance(SessionFactoryObjectFactory.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.close(SessionFactoryImpl.java:981)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.closeSessionFactory(ConsoleConfiguration.java:411)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.reset(ConsoleConfiguration.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.views.ReloadConfigurationAction.doRun(ReloadConfigurationAction.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.actions.ConsoleConfigurationBasedAction.run(ConsoleConfigurationBasedAction.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BaseSelectionListenerAction.runWithEvent(BaseSelectionListenerAction.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Answer (score 7):

ok I found a solution.
I removed the name in the hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<session-factory name="SessionFactory">
```

now is

```
<session-factory>
```

so hibernate creates its own SessionFacade and dont try to use the one of the JNDI.

The DAO I changed to:

```
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure(
                    "hibernate.cfg.xml")
                    .buildSessionFactory();

            return sessionFactory;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            log.error("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + e);
            throw new IllegalStateException("Initial Session Factory creation failed.");
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

Comment: I have 400 dao classes in my application generated by hbm2java plugin. I think this is not feasible solution....Then i need to modify all the dao generated by hbm2java. Is there any better solution for this query?

Answer (score 0):

I would also note that I still saw "org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry addSessionFactory WARN: HHH000277: Could not bind factory to JNDI" message in the logs after  I removed the name attribute from the configuration file.  The problem turned out to be that I was missing some of the required jars in the CLASSPATH (e.g. antlr-2.7.6.jar). This caused a "Throwable" that was no logged and I assumed the warning was the problem. Once I added the missing jars, hibernate 4 worked fine in a Java stand-alone (non-managed) application with JNDI.